# Java web application security - sign, ssl & csr

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, sign, csr

With the Java 8 security update, uploading a java application onto a webpage has been a nightmare. Self-signing is no longer a valid option (as it appears to me). I have recently bought a GeoTrust RapidSSL certificate in hopes that the website will be secured enough for Java not to block the application, but hasn't been like that (its been so confusing all-round).

My webhost setup the ssl so its there, website uses https. But the second area needs to be configured (I'm thinking by me), it wants me to choose the 'Web Server Type' which I believe its CPanel & WHM and underneath 'CSR' (image: http://postimg.org/image/jdnjjt6gr/).

Now I use Eclipse, and I installed this Keytool plugin (link: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/keytool) which allows me to create a keystore & csr (I really have no idea what a keystore, keytool, csr and jks are; I tried to study them on docs and available websites but its just all confusing). When i tried to create a simple one it gave me a bunch of numbers which Im presuming is encrypted with a Begin and a End on its borders (top and bottom).

I'm really confused on what I need to do, I just want to get my application running - I'm just really annoyed by this security block. What can I do? or What am I supposed to do? & Could anyone briefly explain what keystore, keytool, csr and jks are briefly?

Thanks in advance. If you could simplify things and/or give examples, that would be extremely helpful.